# how to install maven library in a global init script on databricks?

Tags: maven, databricks

How to install a maven library (e.g. com.microsoft.azure:spark-mssql-connector_2.12:1.1.0) for all clusters, e.g. using a global init script?

Installing a workspace library and setting it to global is deprecated >= DBR 7. What is the new recommended approach?

Please don't hit me with "just use terraform". The context is a minimalistic example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to put all necessary jars to DBFS, and then copy from DBFS inside the init script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

cp /dbfs/<DBFS-path>/*.jar /databricks/jars/
```

But you need to figure out which dependencies of [this package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/spark-mssql-connector) are necessary as well - many jars are already included into the Databricks Runtime so adding copies may lead to conflicts.